Handling duplicate records when writing Spark dataframes to an Azure SQL Server database using Databricks
Problem statement:
We have a Databricks job with multiple tasks running in parallel. Each task is writing a Spark dataframe to an Azure SQL Database table. Each task writes to its own target table. Some write thousands of records but a few of them millions. The process is a truncate-load due the nature of the design, it is also tricky to make it an incremental process.
This process was working fine initially. But after adding some larger table loads, we occasionally experience duplicate rows in a SQL Server table after the write. We analyzed these records and figured that it is related to one of the dataframe partitions being written twice. We don't know the exact root cause, but assume it is related to a communication issue between SQL Server -> Spark cluster, where SQL Server informs Spark to retry the task while the records were actually already written and commited. Potentially due to throttling at Azure SQL Database side as DTU usage does cap at 100% during the load.
Code for the write:
def write_to_sqldb_table(self, df: DataFrame, target_table_name: str, num_partitions: int = 1) -> None:

        df.write.format("SQLSERVER").option("host", self.sql_host_name).option("database", self.sql_db_name).option(
            "dbtable", target_table_name
        ).option("user", self.sql_user_id).option("password", self.sql_user_password).option("truncate", "true").option(
            "batchsize", self.batch_size
        ).option("numPartitions", num_partitions).mode("overwrite").save()


batch_size is set at 10.000, in the past we performance tested on this and this seems to perform the best.
num_partitions is calculated relative of the records of the dataframe: total_records/batch_size, and then rounded to the nearest multiple of 4 as our cluster has a multiple of 4 cores

What have we tried so far
Defining unique constraints on the SQL Table and handling the error in PySpark

The unique constraints did what they had to do: make the Spark task fail on duplicate records being inserted
Tried handling the error in Spark by checking for the text "UNIQUE Constraint violation" and then returning from the function, but couldn't get this to work. The Spark job kept failing instead of catching the error and proceeding with the remaining inserts until job completes successfully.

def write_to_sqldb_table_with_error_handling(self, df: DataFrame, target_table_name: str, num_partitions: int = 1) -> None:

        try:
            df.write.format("SQLSERVER").option("host", self.sql_host_name).option("database", self.sql_db_name).option(
                "dbtable", target_table_name
            ).option("user", self.sql_user_id).option("password", self.sql_user_password).option("truncate", "true").option(
                "batchsize", self.batch_size
            ).option("numPartitions", num_partitions).mode("overwrite").save()

        except Exception as e:
            error_message = str(e)

            if "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint" in error_message:
                return
            else:
                raise e

Defining unique constraints on the SQL Table and enabling the IGNORE_DUP_KEY option on Table level

The insert operations for the larger tables were being deadlocked after implementing the IGNORE_DUP_KEY.
Tried reducing batch_size, but this didn't help.

Request:
We are looking for a robust solution of avoiding duplicate inserts while maintaining good performance. I'm currently thinking about the following 2 solutions to try out, but looking for any input or experiences from others that could be helpful!

option 1: using the Apache Spark Connector for Azure SQL with reliabilityLevel = "NO_DUPLICATES"

this connector often pops-up in discussions related to improving performance when writing a Spark dataframe -> Azure SQL database
the latest release only supports Spark 3.4, while we are on Spark 3.5, but I guess it is worth a shot


option 2: handling the deduplication on SQL Server side, by including an IDENTITY column as Technical Key on the SQL Server tables and calling a Stored Procedure from my Spark job to remove the duplicates after the insert operation



For my opinion you can do the both, build solution in database (it can be IDENTITY as you mention or another temp table for each insert portion and then insert to main table with NOT EXISTS statement, you can execute it by trigger after insert commit, truncating the table between each insert). And also to see if you can use some solution from Spark side)

DTU utilization at 100%, SQL throttling can cause retries, which introduces concurrency issues like this.
To reduce this SQL throttling and hitting DTU uses you can try below options:

Reducing the partition count or lowering the number of parallel tasks writing to Azure SQL Database can reduce the SQL throttling.
Batch size need to be reduced to manage the higher load on larger tables. Start by reducing it by half and monitor DTU usage.

You can implement SQL solution like below:

Use a merge approach.

Load data into a staging table in SQL from Spark.
Perform an SQL MERGE to replace and insert existing records in the target table with the staging data in sql end.


This approach avoids truncation and reduces the risk of inconsistencies due to retries.


Thanks for the suggestions.
Reducing the parallel tasks is worth a try, although I feel that the SQL Server database is always going at full speed and using 100% DTU. Regardless of the batch-size and amount of partitions.
MERGE approach is not really an option as we don't have proper keys on these tables - which is another problem on its own - I know. But I could run a Stored Procedure on the staging table to remove the duplicates before inserting to target. Or maybe cleaner is to truncate target table and inserts distinct records from staging table, all within a single transaction.

As you don't have proper keys on tables so Running a Stored Procedure to remove duplicates before inserting into the target table is a good approach
